# Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel Version 12.0.0.0 missing from Global Assembly Cache

Tags: c#, clickonce, report-viewer2012

I have a click once application that the installation worked flawlessly. I had to re-image my laptop and start over. Now I am getting problems that the required assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel Version 12.0.0.0' is missing from the GAC.

[image: screen cap]

Answer (score 0):

I needed version 14.0.0.0 of this dll and found it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio`